# getElementsByClassName('el')[0] undefined

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="b1"></div>
<div class="b2"></div>
<div class="b3"></div>
```

```
function create(htmlStr){
    var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    temp = document.createElement('div');
    temp.innerHTML = htmlStr;
    while (temp.firstChild){
        frag.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
    }
    return frag;
}

var _bM=document.getElementsByClassName('.b'+1);

_bM.appendChild(create('<img src="'+some_data+'"class="q q'+some_var+'"/>'));
```

> `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<NodeList> has no method 'appendChild'`

where as:

```
var _bM=document.getElementsByClassName('.b'+1)[0];
```

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of undefined`

im on chrome version 31. Im trying to do pure javascript not jquery as i need speed and must use class not id. why is this happening?

Comment: The class name does not include `.`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `document.getElementsByClassName('b'+1)` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName('.b'+1)`

You don't need `.` with `getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 1):

You should not prefix the class names with a dot in JavaScript. Simply `var _bM=document.getElementsByClassName('b'+1)[0];` will do.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers. If you need a cross-browser solution, and speed is important, try to use this script. Works in all modern and legacy browsers. Uses super fast querySelectorAll. If not available, degrades to native getElementsByClassName. If also not available, still does it (slower, but still works even in very old IEs). Here's a code:

```
function gEByClass(cName, el) {
getElementsByClass = function(getClass){
el = el||document;
if(el.querySelectorAll) {
return el.querySelectorAll("." + getClass);
}
else if(el.getElementsByClassName) {
return el.getElementsByClassName(getClass);
}
else {
var list = el.getElementsByTagName('*'), i = list.length,
classArray = getClass.split(/\s+/), result = [];
while(i--) {
if(list[i].className.search('\\b' + classArray + '\\b') != -1) {
result.push(list[i]);
}
}
return result;
}
};
return getElementsByClass(cName);
}
```